# How do I get rbenv to keep debugging symbols?

Tags: ruby, gdb, valgrind, rbenv, dsym

I installed the development version of Ruby 2 via `rbenv` on Mac OS X v10.8.3, and am using it to compile a gem I'm working on. I have a memory problem I want to debug. Unfortunately, whenever I run `valgrind`, `gdb`, or `cgdb` in the context of a `rake spec`, I get a [whole bunch of errors](https://gist.github.com/mohawkjohn/5535509#file-rake-spec) like this one:

```
warning: Could not find object file "/private/var/folders/5f/h1s00nhn0rv4ckkpg4k_bwhr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20130331232604.54521/ruby-2.0.0-dev/main.o" - no debug information available for "main.c".
```

Obviously, that `ruby-build` directory no longer exists.

I get a [series of likely-related errors](https://gist.github.com/mohawkjohn/5535509#file-rake-spec-valgrind-head) from `valgrind`. Here are examples:

```
--2564-- /Users/jwoods/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-dev/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib:
--2564-- dSYM directory is missing; consider using --dsymutil=yes
```

If I try to use that `--dsymutil=yes` option, I get errors which are basically the same as those from `gdb`:

```
warning: (x86_64) /private/var/folders/5f/h1s00nhn0rv4ckkpg4k_bwhr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20130331232604.54521/ruby-2.0.0-dev/ext/openssl/ossl_bn.o unable to open object file
```

Per an answer to another question, I tried running `info target` inside `gdb`. [Here is the output.](https://gist.github.com/mohawkjohn/5535509#file-gdb-info-target)

Is there some way I can instruct `rbenv` to put the debugging symbols somewhere that they won't get cleaned up?

I'm using GCC 4.7.1, which I installed via homebrew. My exact Ruby version string is `ruby 2.1.0dev (2013-04-01 trunk 40029) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]`, and my `rbenv` version is 0.4.0.

Comment: Please move the errors and gdb output into your question. Links get stale and/or break due to link-rot. Once that happens your question will be unusable for people looking to get answers for the same problem. Also, by putting your information off-site, you're forcing those who might want to help to chase it down, which wastes their time. Help us help you by putting the information here instead.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have precisely the same question, details included.

Comment: Sort of, though I haven't tried to apply it to `rbenv`. I suppose when you compile rbenv and Ruby you have to actually run `dsymutil` on the resulting binaries. This is the only way I've gotten Mac to keep my debugging symbols.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation for [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build#keeping-the-build-directory-after-installation):

> Both ruby-build and rbenv install accept the -k or --keep flag, which tells ruby-build to keep the downloaded source after installation. This can be useful if you need to use gdb and memprof with Ruby.

So try `ruby-build install X -k`, where X is the version number.